# Automated testing for tmLanguage and sublime-syntax files?

Tags: testing, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, tmlanguage

Is it possible to create automated tests for a `*.tmLanguage` or `*.sublime-syntax` file? What is the best practices for doing that?

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html - search for `Testing`. Then, when you are in a `sublime-syntax` file or a `syntax_test` file, you can use the ST build system to run the tests.

Comment: How can you do that? I've been trying to do it, but can seem to make it work. the syntax documentation states that running "build" should do the trick, however it does not seem to do anything for me.

Comment: There is [`vscode-tmgrammar-test`](https://github.com/PanAeon/vscode-tmgrammar-test) to test `tmLanguage` for VS Code; I assume that the `tmLanguage` files are compatible (they actually came from TextMate), so it might also help you (or future visitors from Google).

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use SublimeLinter with plugins, since you get instant feedback while working on a file. [xmllint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-xmllint) works for `*.tmLanguage`, and [pyyaml](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pyyaml) for `*.sublime-syntax`.

Personally, I'm using a [gruntfile](https://github.com/idleberg/sublimetext-gruntfile.js) to test my packages, but that's not as integrated as using SublimeLinter. However, it can be used with Travis CI and the likes.